A functor preserving mapping cones is triangulated
Consider a functor $F: \operatorname{HChains}(A) \to \operatorname{HChains}(A)$, where $A$ is an abelian category and $\operatorname{HChains}(A)$ the category of chain complexes modulo chain homotopy equivalence. This of course is a triangulated category with distinguished triangles given by mapping cone triangles
$$ X \xrightarrow{\varphi} Y \to \operatorname{Con}(\varphi) \to X[1]. $$
I am wondering whether the following is true:

If $F$ preserves cones and shifts, then it preserves distinguished triangles.

If we have such an $F$ inducing an isomorphism $F(\operatorname{Con}(\varphi)) \xrightarrow{\sim} \operatorname{Con}(F(\varphi))$, it would be natural to consider the following diagram:

Here the bottom row is the distinguished triangle which belongs to $\operatorname{Con}(F(\varphi))$. However, it is not clear to me why the diagram commutes.
Does this diagram indeed commute or is there another way to show the result?

Probably $F$ is additive? And do you really only regard the cones without their relations to the domain and codomain? That's not good, you lose essential structure. What you ask is certainly correct with the correct interpretation of the question.

Yes, the functor is assumed to be additive! I do not quite understand what you mean "without relations to the domain and codomain". If you mean that $F$ should also preserve $(0, \operatorname{id}Y): Y \to \operatorname{Con}(\varphi)$ and $(\operatorname{id}{X[1]}, 0): \operatorname{Con}(\varphi) \to X[1]$, then of course the diagram commutes. But then the statement is kind of a tautology...

Exactly, it's true in the correct setting. When will you ever be able to show in practice that cones are preserved without any reference to their domain and codomain?
